# bash alias gets imported with 'alias' prefix

Tags: bash, alias

I have a weird issue with the `.bash_aliases` file.

I have some aliases in this file and when I `source` this file to `.bashrc`, the aliases get imported with the `'alias'` suffix, instead of being executed. 
So when I type `# alias`, I get a list of aliases with the `'alias'` prefix, instead of getting the list of aliases:

```
alias env1=...
alias env2=...
...
alias env1000=...
```

*Additional information:* I'm on RH 6.6

Comment: That is what I get too. But it is the correct behaviour, according to the command  `help alias`: Without arguments, `alias' prints the list of aliases in the reusable
    form `alias NAME=VALUE` on standard output. Maybe you want to strip away "alias" from each line of the listing. In that case `cut` is useful: alias|cut -f2- -d' '

Comment: By the way, this might not be the right place for your question. Next time try the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange (https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The aliases are correctly set, this just happens to be how bash shows them by default.  To get the POSIX output format as seen in dash and other shells:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 alias
```

Here's an example:

```
bash-4.4$ alias foo=bar

bash-4.4$ alias
alias foo='bar'

bash-4.4$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 alias
foo='bar'
```